# Is there a way to loop through the visible cells in a table (listobject) column?

Tags: excel, loops, visible, listobject

In an Excel table (`ListObject`), I've begun tracking hundreds of movies and their status as I rip them to disc to use in Plex. The table is nothing fancy; it stores things you'd expect like the ripping folder, the Plex media folder, the name of the movie, the year it was released, the backup folder where I store a copy of the raw disc files, etc. I created the workbook after I had already done several hundred movies to make tracking easier. As a result of inconsistency in my methods before I created the workbook, I now have some cleanup to do in the workbook. I want to do it using VBA as manually corrections would be tedious, error-prone and take a long time. I have an algorithm that I believe will work, but it relies on the ability to loop through the visible cells in a column of a filtered table -- the column that I will use to determine if I need to make any corrections on that row, and then where needed, the columns where corrections need to be made.

Any guidance here would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Why does the looping have to take place over filtered rows? Why can't the conditions which are being applied as table filters be translated into conditional statements within the loop?

Comment: Good question. Short answer is because I expect the conditions to change in a way that I cannot predict because they're based on whatever mistakes I make in the future. I've done 400 movies; I have about 1000 to go, and for efficiency, I have 3 machines setup to process them, thus I'll be updating the workbook from all 3 machines (which have different local drives that may be used for the intermediate ripping stage). The process is tedious and long, so I expect that I'll make some mistakes going forward. So I want this corrective process to be flexible enough to handle this.

Comment: Another reason @JosWoolley is because I want to limit the scope -- and potential damage -- the routine might do in case there is a bug in my code, and using only a subset of my data when the code runs limits where I'll need to inspect for errors.

I'm not sure if you asked because what I want to do is either not possible or inadvisable. In either case, I'd like to know as I have only intermediate skills with VBA and I'm here to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

Set MyTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

With MyTable
    For i = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If .DataBodyRange.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            [Do Something]
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Replace `[Do Something]` with your desired action for the visible rows, for example:

```
Sub Test()

Set MyTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

With MyTable
    For i = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If .DataBodyRange.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            .DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value = "I'm not hidden!"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

which enters "I'm not hidden!" into the third column of that table for each visible row.

Comment: Thanks @joswoolley. I implemented a modified version of your solution and it works well! I had seen the `.EntireRow` property before, but wasn't aware that it had a `.Hidden` attribute. And the sheer number of ways that look like they might work made trial and error tedious. You save me much time!